# Automate login page

Tags: javascript, html, instagram

I'm trying to automate the login on Instagram using only pure Javascript. (https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/) .

Here is how the inputs look like :

```
<input class="_2hvTZ pexuQ zyHYP" id="f3276ee98b5533" aria-label="Phone number, username, or email" aria-required="true" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" maxlength="75" name="username" type="text" value="">
<input class="_2hvTZ pexuQ zyHYP" id="f184fc168fd6684" aria-label="Password" aria-required="true" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" name="password" type="password" value="">
```

For achieve the login, i'm using the code below :

```
document.getElementsByName('username')[0].value = 'me@myemail.com';
document.getElementsByName('password')[0].value = 'mypassword';
```

Problem is, even if i run the code above, the inputs are filled but the 'Log in' button won't enable and the inputs' placeholder won't go away ; it's like the inputs are not filled, like the image below ; what else should i do to achieve the login only using Javascript ?

[image]

Comment: Maybe it's listening to an onchange event for the button, you could try to trigger it manually with element.onchange(); Also, if you're automating it, wouldnt sending the POST itself be more logical?

Comment: Really are you writing *https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/*? Do you work @Instagram ???

Comment: I am guessing that Login button enables/disables on one of the events on input fields. Look for events triggered by those 2 fields and either call whichever method they call manually or triger that event.

Comment: @Viezevingertjes I'm doing it for study purposes, i want to understand how can i t be made using only JS... The onchange don't work

Comment: @zero Tried a lot (onchange, onkeydown an so on) but could not suceed :(

Comment: you can do that using https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer, and simulate typing username and password, as well as clicking login button - it is all in js (actually, nodejs) .

Comment: Well, I looked through some of their javascripts and found this attached to a disabled button:
`onClick:this.$SlimLoginForm6`. If you can use jQuery, you can probably call this function to artificially submit.

Comment: @Zero I'm trying to do it with pure JS

Comment: You're injecting the javascript in the page, right? then jQuery should automatically be available, as it's being used by the page itself.

Comment: @Viezevingertjes element.onchange() returns me the error "Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).onchange is not a function"

Answer (score 1):

This is likely to break in future updates, but it appears that all of their code (at least the one you need) is in [this JS file](https://www.instagram.com/static/bundles/metro/LoginAndSignupPage.js/7fb31375b4f3.js). It looks like that js creates the portion of login page that you are interested in, so I'm guessing you can work the rest out.

Username field

```
className:f,maxLength:75,name:"username",onChange:this.$SlimLoginForm5,placeholder:h,value:this.state.username}
```

button event.

```
onClick:this.$SlimLoginForm6
```

First of all it seems that `onChange` event is what enables/disables the button, but you have to pass it username (if you just trigger that event without passing any parameters it will be treated like user name is empty and therefore login button stays disabled).

Secondly, `onClick` event is on that button (although it's also hidden if you look at the actual HTML.....), so you should be able to submit by invoking `onClick` event.

I hope you can figure out how to pass a value to the `onChange` event, because I can't really help you there... :P

From there on it should be straightforward.

Comment: How can i call the '$SlimLoginForm5' ? I call it and get an error : "VM75:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: SlimLoginForm5 is not defined"

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are doing this in Tampermonkey / Greasemonkey / Scratchpad or something alike.

Why do you care about the labels (which are, frankly, idiotic on Instagram's side; just use `<input placeholder="text" ...>`) when you want to auto-login?

Just add `document.forms[0].submit();` ...

Comment: This won't work, it seems the inputs aren't posted as an error page says 'This page could not be loaded. If you have cookies disabled in your browser, or you are browsing in Private Mode, please try enabling cookies or turning off Private Mode, and then retrying your action.'

Comment: I see. I thought the error was due to using fake credentials. It's terrible how a simple login page can't be just fricken HTML nowadays. I used to learn in a time when people were told to not rely on JavaScript being active / available. Have you taken a look at  the onclick event's code? It can be shortened to `o.$SlimLoginForm1 = !0, o.props.onSubmit(o.state.username, o.state.password, !0 === o.props.optLinkAccounts && o.state.optIntoLinkedAccounts)`, but it's still minified code ...

Comment: Is there a way to call these functions directly via JS, without needing fill the inputs ?